# Laravel Blade: Show two fields of the same array in

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

i wanna show this array, that is a result of a eloquent query:

```
 $resultados = $this->model::all()->pluck('descricao','datapagamento');
```

[image]

I can loop to the separated fields like this:

```
    @foreach ($data as $datas)
        {{ $datas }}<br />
    @endforeach
```

but when i try to loop through the $resultados, that contais two fields, it only show one field of the array

[image]

and when i show the variable without look it works fine

[image]

my goal is to do this layout

[image]

Comment: foreach ($data as $key=> $datas)
       {{ $key}}    {{ $datas }}<br /> .removed @ since its not allowed mutiple times in comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must change the loop and include the key:

```
@foreach ($data as $key => $datas)
    {{ $key }}: {{ $datas }}<br />
@endforeach
```